# 301 redirect feedback.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I tried to add redirect for 404 links which started to appear some time ago.
That is the link structure

`http://www.domain.com/plugins/feedback.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F571%2Fczerwone-bmw-extra-felgi&_fb_noscript=1`

I have added such redirect in .htaccess file but it's not working. Can you advice what I did wrong? Sorry I'm not very good in programming.

```
RewriteRule ^feedback.php(.*)$ http://www.domain.com [L]
```

I wanted to re-direct all those bad links to main domain.

Comment: What's not working? Can you show your full .htaccess

Comment: Helo it`s not redirecting that bad addresses to main page it`s looks like this :


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /plugins/^feedback.php(.*)$ http://www.motopictures.com [R=301,L]

http://www.motopictures.com/plugins/feedback.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.motopictures.com%2F924%2Fbugatti-veyron&_fb_noscript=1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^href=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/? [L,R]
```

Comment: but there are multiple events, so I need to address the dinamically somehow - that was just an example can you help ?

Comment: Anyone ? who can help ?

Comment: The problem is that URL is dynamic for multiple links i just added example. Do you have any idea how to redirect all such links ?

Comment: yes this is the example
http://www.motopictures.com/plugins/feedback.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.motopictures.com%2F924%2Fbugatti-veyron&_fb_noscript=1

Comment: Do you have any idea  Starkeen ?

Comment: See the edit. I have replaced url with (.+) , it matches any query string value dynimically